# Как достать значение переменной из класса?

Tags: python, классы

Допустим, есть класс:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, num1 = 0, num2 = 0):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

e = Example()
```

Как мне вывести на экран значение num1? Создавать функции нельзя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так:

```
e = Example()
print(e.num1)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!